# Material UI Datagrid/XGrid renderHeader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

there is a section from material UI about renderHeader in datagrid and Xgrid components

https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/columns/#render-header

and it fairly describes how to add additional content into header, but what if I need to add filter component there, lets say dropdown. Is there any possible way how to preventDefault() the xhr request?

I got implemented sorting there I wanna keep it, but omit the filter component from it, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found out, that there is not default action for inputs. So nothing to prevent, instead  **event.stopPropagation()** did the job for me, so now input behaves exactly as I wished and surrounding elements still have sorting ability.

Comment: could you please share the code? I also face the same problem

Comment: @JabalLogian hey, here is the whole thread how I disscused it on github with MUI developers and I found soluution to this :-)

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/1915

the thread is not that long so you can read it thru, but since the slution they released mui 5 and new production version of Datagrid, will try to fidn answer in our code

Comment: @JabalLogian TLDR: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-bgyj7?file=/demo.tsx

 just beware the code is not working in latest firefox for me. We have decided to support our app only in chrome, where it works :-)